# DNS Zone Name

Tags: dns

In a DNS zone file, for the type 'A', what is the difference between the name '*' and the name'@'?

What does each do?

```
* A myIp

@ A myIp
```

Also if anyone knows a nice tutorial on editing and fine-tuning DNS zone file in general I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @ symbol means that nothing comes before the domain name and * means that anything can come before the domain name.

Refer: http://www.ipprimer.com/dns.cfm

Comment: this is misleading - an `@` just means "the current zone name" and can appear on the right hand side too.

Answer (score 2):

The `@` symbol represents the current (fully qualified) zone name, as usually set with `$ORIGIN`.

The `*` symbol is the wildcard label - the DNS server will respond to queries for *unknown* labels with the data from here